# Bubble sort code on Java

Tags: java

This code was supposed to be a Bubble sort but Eclipse keep telling me there are syntax errors on line 9:

```
- Syntax error on token "(", { expected  
- Syntax error on token "arr", ( expected after this token
```

Anyone knows what is happening?

```
package porra;

public class Vai {

public static final int ARRAYLEN = 0;

public static void main(String[] args){

class bubbleSort (int[] arr) { 

boolean swap = true;
int i = 0, j = 0, temp;
while (swap) {
    swap = false;
    j++;
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAYLEN - j; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
            arr[i + 1] = temp;
            swap = true;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Ordem" + j + " : ");
    this.printArray(arr);
    System.out.println("");
}
return;
}
private void printArray(int[] arr2) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing class declaration with constructor declaration.  Do this:

```
class bubbleSort{
  public static sort(int[] arr){
    boolean swap = true;
    ...etc...
    System.out.println("");
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] nums = {1,43,7,8};
    bubbleSort.sort(nums);
  }
}
```

Comment: don't use the constructor as a replacement for main(). It is the place to construct the object, not to run the code. If you want a class with one method doing one task, use a static method. Never use the constructor!

Comment: Agree 100%.  He's obviously new.  1 thing at a time.

Comment: Then fix your sample, not to show such stuff. I saw too many applications written exactly like that. Just make it a `BubbleSort.sort(nums)` and I am happy.

Comment: Fixed.  Although it's quite a few steps from the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

and Eclipse is RIGHT! :-)

> ```
> public static void main(String[] args){
> class bubbleSort (int[] arr) {
> ```

you start a class, you start the main method, and in the main method you start to define the class and this definition has parameters, that is not allowed.

The class Bubblesort is inside a class Vai, is that your intention, using an inner class?

I suggest you return to your textbook and check the syntax of a class definition.

Comment: Classes can absolutely be defined inside methods. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html

Comment: ok, agreed. yet, while he can do it doesnt mean he should do it.

Comment: it is what? the class can not have parameters as presented, it can have a type list if it is generic.